PHP memory allocation for exit message
This question comes from an issue I've ran it.
The server is supposed to die() with a file in the message, but doing this allocates too much memory for the script and it throws a Fatal Error.
Is this intended behavior? The string is passed to it so why does it make an copy of it? Are there any smart workarounds to this that wouldn't be to just increase the memory cap?
While this was mostly to learn how PHP works, the code solution I need has to work with header() to properly handle returning a file

Here is a small PoC that i made to demo the issue. It's not the best but as smart as I could figure out in 10 minutes.
It throws Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes) in mem_tester.php on line 11
<?php

// set this to whatever it says currently using is if you start from 0
$mem = 0;
ini_set('memory_limit', $mem);

// might need more repeats if it does not crash
$str = str_repeat(".", $mem / 2);
//echo $str; // this also allocates
//exit($str); // same as die, but for certainty
die($str);


Did you try ob_start();echo $str;ob_end_flush();exit();?

Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message you get.

@Progman added the message

@RoyBogado it still is trying to allocate more memory

What's the version of PHP?

@shingo 8.3 is what I'm running but this also occurs on 8.2

The main reason for this problem is that output_buffering is enabled.
For some reason (but IDK the reason, and IDT this is intended), when you try to output a large string, even if you only set a reasonable output buffer size, PHP will still allocate a sufficiently memory and copy the string into it without hesitation. The comment in the source code just says:

/* store it away */

So the solution is to disable output buffering, you can consider 2 options:

Set output_buffering = Off in php.ini

Call ob_end_flush before outputing a large string.



Hmm, just doing step 2 seems to made my demo test be able to print out the file without allocating beyond the memory limit. I shall investigate further but this seems like the wanted result, even with die()

These are two options.

Ah right. Well the #1 does not work if called via ini_set so I shall go with #2 and see if it will come with some odd behavio. But from initiall testing it seems to be what I wanted

You could split the data into chunks and output it seperatly:
$size = $mem / 2;
while ($size > 0) {
    $chunk = min(8192, $size); // Process 8KB at a time
    echo str_repeat(".", $chunk);
    $size -= $chunk;
}
exit();

Or use PHP streaming capabilities:
$stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$size = $mem / 2;
while ($size > 0) {
    $chunk = min(8192, $size);
    fwrite($stream, str_repeat(".", $chunk));
    $size -= $chunk;
}
fclose($stream);
exit();

Hope this helps!

I tried the streaming method and it still failed cause the str_repeat was just used as an example to create a large variable, so to split it I went with substr but it still runs out of memory mid-write. Any better suggestion to split the output string?
